# Expression : String subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, stack, abstract-data-type

```
#include "stack.h"
int main()
{
   Stack <char> s;
   string str;
   cout<<"Enter a string"<<endl;
   cin>>str;
   cout<<str<<endl;
   for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
   {
     s.push(str[i]);
   }

   s.makeEmpty();
   return 0;
}
```

Here i am trying to reverse string using stack, but it is giving me subscript out of range error.Here is code for makeEmpty() function.

```
void Stack<T>::makeEmpty()
{
 Node<T>* temp;
 while(topPtr!=NULL)
 {
    cout<<topPtr->data;
    temp=topPtr;
    topPtr=topPtr->next;
    delete temp;
 }
}
```

Where node is a structure

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
  T data;
  Node<T>* next;
};
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)` could use str.size()  instead. Or you could replace this with a rage based for loop `for( const char& ch : str) { ...`

Comment: where and when in the program execution does the error occur?

Comment: C++ `strings` objects are not `null-terminated` like  array of characters. In your loop use `i < strong.size()` instead.

Comment: @yabhishek -- you're right, before C++11. Starting with C++11, `str[str.size()]` is required to return a nul character. But looping up to `str.size()` is still the better approach.

Comment: @yabhishek Starting from C++ 11 the loop is correct except that the type of the variable i should not be int.:)

Comment: `i` should be an int, or do you index your strings using characters?